# Configure WindowsOS host such that the given address leads to CentOS 7 virtual machine in VMWare

Tags: linux, centos, windows, virtual-machine, vmware

I have the following question:

How to configure WindowsOS host (native OS) such that the address: 'local.myvirtualmachine.com' leads to CentOS 7 virtual machine in VMWare?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve 'local.myvirtualmachine.com' to an IP address of your choosing (192.168.1.13 in this example), edit your hosts file (typically C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\Hosts) and place the IP address and hostname at the end of the file:

```
192.168.1.13    local.myvirtualmachine.com
```

By the way, this has nothing to do with linux, centos or vmware.